# bower - developing a component while using it

Tags: bower

Lets say I have project A and B. Project B depends on Project A.

I am working on project A and I would like to see immediate results by running project B.

My co-worker is working on project B and is not allowed to check-out the code for project A at all!

In Maven+Intellij I can easily do this for Java projects. I can define module dependencies in Intellij which allows me to work on project A and run project B with my modifications. For my co-worker Maven will fetch the deployed artifact on our local repository.

Now I am trying to implement the same work-flow for front-end development. (images, HTML, JavaScript).

I decided to go with Bower which seems "straight and to the point".

How can I achieve these 2 qualities I have with Maven and Intellij:

1. Change a dependency and with "refresh" see results.
2. Define a different dependency for different developers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can only answer the first question as I have never used these IDEs.

You can use `bower link` to symlink project A into project B.

Run `bower link -h` for more info.

Comment: I am not sure this works on windows. I am considering something like "grunt watch" to copy the files on change.

Comment: Windows or rather NTFS does have some kind of symlink like ability, but not sure if Bower supports that.

Comment: For windows, I found it most useful to configure nginx to bridge the gap, but definitely, bower link is the way to go in unix.

Answer (score 10):

Here are the steps for Bower development linking (assuming the project is called `bower-typescript-hello-world`:

In your bower module, go to the root where bower.json is located, and run `bower link`.  This will create a linkable path in your home directory:

`bower    link    ~/.local/share/bower/links/bower-typescript-hello-world > *CURRENT_DIRECTORY*`

Now go to the project that uses this bower package and run `bower link bower-typescript-hello-world`

This will link things up so that the current files are used from the module instead of needing to do a git commit to see the changes.

Comment: Is there a way to link to a folder within the module? For example, if bower-typescript-hello-world had a folder called "dist". It seems to create the link but it's not updating.

Comment: I think in that scenario, you'd want to se bower.json's `main` file to be in that dist folder... shoudn't have anything to do with linking.  Linking is just telling your project to use a local version of the module, not something published on the web.